# how to AirPrint a picture of the whole screen in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I would like to know if there was a way to AirPrint a picture of either the screen or of a page view controller in Xcode 6 I have looked on apples developer website and i have also looked on youtube.

Comment: Have you just googled it in general ?

Comment: yes I have but I have not found anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot with (Command(⌘) + S) while running the IOS simulator.

If you would like a screenshot of something inside of xcode, you can take a screenshot by pressing (Command(⌘) + Shift + 4) and clicking and dragging the crosshairs over whatever you want to save as a screenshot.

In both instances the pictures will be saved onto your desktop.

If you want to print the pictures, you can then just do that from your computer.